# With the action attribute. How do I get action = "practice.php" to load another page after it submit the data to a practice.php file?

Tags: html

When I use `action ="practice.php"`  It will bring up a blank web page with the directory the practice.php file is located in.

```
<form method="post" action = "practice.php">

    <-- <input> here -->
        Person's Name: <input name="personname" type="text" /> </br>
        Person's Name: <input name="personname" type="text" /> </br>

    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>

</form>
```

Comment: You're obviously following some tutorial, we'd need to know more about where you are running this code.  Php needs to be set up to activate on your webserver, and that's where the trouble typically lies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use redirect, in `practice.php` have a `header('Location: someotherpage');` to do a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be asking two distinct questions. I'll answer the question in your title.

Use the header() function with the "Location" attribute set to the location you want to redirect to. In the following example, I prepended a PHP script to your HTML script. The script simply dumps the contents of $_POST which will happen regardless of what $_POST contains and then checks for the "personname" array in $_POST. If "personname" exists it redirects to "Location: /newpage.php".

You could do some other processing in place of just dumping the contents of $_POST prior to redirecting if you like.

I also changed the "name" attributes to your input elements so that the multiple "personname" values are delivered to PHP in an array rather than just delivering the last one in a scalar variable.

I also changed "<-- <input> here-->" to "<!-- <input> here-->". It looks like you were trying to make this a comment.

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    if ( $_POST['personname'] > '' ) {
        header("Location: /newpage.php");
    }
?>

<form method="post" action = "practice.php">

    <!-- <input> here -->
        Person's Name: <input name="personname[]" type="text" /> </br>
        Person's Name: <input name="personname[]" type="text" /> </br>

    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>

</form>
```

Comment: Could I use isset with $_POST instead of the $_POST[personname] > "" to check for contents of $_POST?

Comment: Yes you could. Mine also checks that it is not an empty string but both check to see that it is set in some way.